# Process multiline JSON file without Commas at the end of new Record

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mongodb

I have a multiline JSON File with no commas after a new record. I have tried to read it using both JSON and BSON libraries but it's not working. Below are the sample two records from the file.

```
{ 
    "_id" : , 
    "form" : , 
    "owner" : , 
    "deleted" : null, 
    "metadata" : [
], 
"data" : {
    "action" : "Document Uploaded", 
    "comments" : "New Document Added", 
    "descriptionEventLog" : "Ledger", 
    "status" : "Needs More Info", 
    "submissionIdCase" : "", 
    "timestamp" : "", 
    "type" : "", 
    "user" : "", 
    "submissionIdPaymentBatch" : "", 
    "submissionIdPayment" : "", 
    "reason" : ""
}, 
"validationErrors" : [

], 
"formArchive" : null, 
"isRevision" : false, 
"moduleArchiveIdAtCreated" : , 
"platformVersionAtCreated" : "6.72.5-2023-02-08", 
"created" : ISODate("2023-02-27T17:14:11.560+0000"), 
"modified" : ISODate("2023-02-27T17:14:11.561+0000"), 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
}

{ 
    "_id" : , 
    "form" : , 
    "owner" : "", 
    "deleted" : null, 
    "metadata" : [

], 
"data" : {
    "action" : "Document Uploaded", 
    "comments" : "New Document Added", 
    "descriptionEventLog" : "Lease", 
    "status" : "Needs More Info", 
    "submissionIdCase" : "", 
    "timestamp" : "", 
    "type" : "", 
    "user" : "", 
    "submissionIdPaymentBatch" : "", 
    "submissionIdPayment" : "", 
    "reason" : ""
}, 
"validationErrors" : [

], 
"formArchive" : null, 
"isRevision" : false, 
"moduleArchiveIdAtCreated" : ObjectId("60e631e70b10c402e799dede"), 
"platformVersionAtCreated" : "6.72.5-2023-02-08", 
"created" : ISODate("2023-02-27T17:13:06.428+0000"), 
"modified" : ISODate("2023-02-27T17:13:06.428+0000"), 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I have tried both json.load and json.loads but it is not working.

Can anyone share some leads to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you're receving? also, what is that json? `null` is not a keyword in python and `NumberInt` is not something that can be inside of json

Comment: this json was created in result of dump from mongoDB

Answer (score 1):

It would probably best to create a better dump. If that's not possible you could try to use regex to salvage it. The following worked for the sample, but it's very likely that there are other issues in the rest:

```py
import json
import re

re_object = re.compile(r"(?:ObjectId|NumberInt|ISODate)\(([^)]*)\)")
re_no_value = re.compile(r":\s*,")
re_record_break = re.compile(r"}\s*{")

with open("data.json", "r") as file:
    data_str = file.read()
data_str = re_object.sub(r"\g<1>", data_str)
data_str = re_no_value.sub(": null,", data_str)
data_str = "[" + re_record_break.sub("},\n{", data_str) + "]"
data = json.loads(data_str)
```

The regexes address 3 issues:

- There's stuff like `ObjectId(...)`, `NumberInt(...)`, `ISODate(...)`, etc. in the file: Python can't deal with that. The regex tries to pull the resp. values out.
- Then there are parts like `"_id" : ,`. That won't work either. The regex does try to replace them with a `null`, i.e. `"_id" : null,`.
- The missing comma between records: last regex.

Result for the sample:

```
[{'_id': None,
  'form': None,
  'owner': None,
  'deleted': None,
  'metadata': [],
  'data': {'action': 'Document Uploaded',
           'comments': 'New Document Added',
           'descriptionEventLog': 'Ledger',
           'status': 'Needs More Info',
           'submissionIdCase': '',
           'timestamp': '',
           'type': '',
           'user': '',
           'submissionIdPaymentBatch': '',
           'submissionIdPayment': '',
           'reason': ''},
  'validationErrors': [],
  'formArchive': None,
  'isRevision': False,
  'moduleArchiveIdAtCreated': None,
  'platformVersionAtCreated': '6.72.5-2023-02-08',
  'created': '2023-02-27T17:14:11.560+0000',
  'modified': '2023-02-27T17:14:11.561+0000',
  '__v': 0},
 {'_id': None,
  'form': None,
  'owner': '',
  'deleted': None,
  'metadata': [],
  'data': {'action': 'Document Uploaded',
           'comments': 'New Document Added',
           'descriptionEventLog': 'Lease',
           'status': 'Needs More Info',
           'submissionIdCase': '',
           'timestamp': '',
           'type': '',
           'user': '',
           'submissionIdPaymentBatch': '',
           'submissionIdPayment': '',
           'reason': ''},
  'validationErrors': [],
  'formArchive': None,
  'isRevision': False,
  'moduleArchiveIdAtCreated': '60e631e70b10c402e799dede',
  'platformVersionAtCreated': '6.72.5-2023-02-08',
  'created': '2023-02-27T17:13:06.428+0000',
  'modified': '2023-02-27T17:13:06.428+0000',
  '__v': 0}]
```